# Unable to implement any logic to scrape content from innermost pages using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I've created a script using puppeteer to scrape the links of different authors from a [webpage](https://quotes.toscrape.com/) traversing multiple pages triggering click on the next page button. The script appears to be working in the right way.

Although the content of this site is static, I intentionally used puppeteer within the following script only to learn as to how I can parse content from inner pages.

Given that I wish to go one layer deep to scrape `description` from such [pages](https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein/). How can I achieve that?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function run (pagesToScrape) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            if (!pagesToScrape) {
                pagesToScrape = 1;
            }
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
            const [page] = await browser.pages();
            await page.goto("https://quotes.toscrape.com/");
            let currentPage = 1;
            let urls = [];
            while (currentPage <= pagesToScrape) {
                let newUrls = await page.evaluate(() => {
                    let results = [];
                    let items = document.querySelectorAll('[class="quote"]');
                    items.forEach((item) => {
                        results.push({
                            authorUrl:  'https://quotes.toscrape.com' + item.querySelector("small.author + a").getAttribute('href'),
                            title: item.querySelector("span.text").innerText
                        });
                    });
                    return results;
                });
                urls = urls.concat(newUrls);
                if (currentPage < pagesToScrape) {
                    await Promise.all([
                        await page.waitForSelector('li.next > a'),
                        await page.click('li.next > a'),
                        await page.waitForSelector('[class="quote"]')
                    ])
                }
                currentPage++;
            }
            browser.close();
            return resolve(urls);
        } catch (e) {
            return reject(e);
        }
    })
}
run(3).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: From the site's Terms of Use: "*Data Mining/Scraping and Framing Prohibited. You may not use bots, scrapers, crawlers, spiders, or any similar methods, processes, or tools to "data mine" or otherwise gather or extract data from the YP Sites...*" I'd be careful posting questions about scraping sites that specifically forbid scraping... Just sayin'. Stack Overflow's not gonna rat you out, nor am I, but this is a public site.

Comment: This time the site is different @Heretic Monkey. The site in the question was created to be scraped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go this way:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let browser;

(async function main() {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null });

  const [pageQuotes] = await browser.pages();
  const pageAbout = await browser.newPage();
  await pageQuotes.bringToFront(); // Otherwise, click on the next page link does not work.

  const pagesToScrape = 3;

  await pageQuotes.goto('https://quotes.toscrape.com/');
  let currentPage = 1;

  const data = { quotes: {}, abouts: {} };
  const visitedAbouts = new Set();

  while (currentPage <= pagesToScrape) {
    await pageQuotes.waitForSelector('.quote');

    const { quotes, aboutURLs } = await pageQuotes.evaluate(() => ({
      quotes: Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll('.quote'),
        quote => [quote.querySelector('small.author').innerText, quote.innerText],
      ),
      aboutURLs: Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll('.quote small.author + a[href]'),
        quote => quote.href,
      ),
    }));

    for (const [author, quote] of quotes) {
      if (data.quotes[author] === undefined) data.quotes[author] = [];
      data.quotes[author].push(quote);
    }

    for (const aboutURL of aboutURLs) {
      if (!visitedAbouts.has(aboutURL)) {
        visitedAbouts.add(aboutURL);

        await pageAbout.goto(aboutURL);
        await pageAbout.waitForSelector('div.author-details');

        const { title, about } = await pageAbout.evaluate(() => ({
          title: document.querySelector('div.author-details h3.author-title').innerText,
          about: document.querySelector('div.author-details').innerText,
        }));

        data.abouts[title] = about;
      }
    }

    if (currentPage < pagesToScrape) {
      const nextLink = await pageQuotes.waitForSelector('li.next > a');

      await Promise.all([
        nextLink.click(),
        pageQuotes.waitForNavigation(),
      ]);
    }
    currentPage++;
  }

  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
})().catch(console.error).finally(async () => { if (browser) await browser.close(); });
```

Comment: As your provided solution to my last post worked smoothly, I thought to accept this answer first before asking any question. My node version is `v13.14.0`. When I ran your suggested approach, I got this error `Unexpected token '?'`. Can I replace this line `data.quotes[author] ??= []` with something suitable for my version? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MITHU Yes, I've edited the answer with older approach.

Comment: This is one of the finest methods I've ever come across. So you have made use of two tabs to deal with the data of two different layers, right? Btw, what is the alternative approach to this `await browser?.close()`? You see the sign ***?*** again.

Comment: @MITHU Right. I've made the replacement for `browser?.close()`.